# PHP find variable inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $this and in order to see what it contains i used print_r() and it happened to contain a lot of data. I need to know what variable produces the value for "user_id". It should be something like $this->user_id but i cant figure it out since its a lot of text. I would paste it here for you to see it but really, its too much. So im pasting just a little extract:

```
Am_Auth_User Object ( [idField:protected] => user_id [loginField:protected] => login [loginType:protected] => 0 [fromCookie:protected] => [userClass:protected] => User [plaintextPass:protected] => [session] => Zend_Session_Namespace Object ( [_namespace:protected] => amember_auth ) [user:protected] => [configPrefix:protected] => [protector:protected] => [di:protected] => Am_Di Object *RECURSION* ) [locale] => Am_Locale Object ( [locale:protected] => ja_JP ) [cacheBackend] => Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels Object ( [_options:protected] => Array ( [slow_backend] => File [fast_backend] => Am_Cache_Backend_Array Object ( [_cache:protected] => Array ( [5dfbcb168a5b232b0ed52a1cb8cfb384] =>
```

Is there any php function that allows me to see all the variables i could use with $this array?

EDIT: I tried with

```
print_r(array_keys($this));
```

and

```
foreach(array_keys($this) as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br>";}
```

and

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        print_r(array_map($this,$a));
```

But none of them produced anything.
Thank you.

Comment: How about this.. http://www.php.net/array_map

Comment: Thats seems to be close to what i need but seems like i need to add an argument like this: print_r(array_map($this, $b)); where $b its the number of arrays, which i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of just the print_r():

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($your_variable, true).'</pre>';
```

That will make it easier to read; (the true parameter returns the print_r results as a string)

Comment: Thanks. Its indeed easier to read but still hard to understand. Isnt there a function that produces the exact variable i have to use to get the value in "user_id"? It should be something like: $this->something->something->user_id

Comment: try hold the ctrl button and hitting the 'f' key.  Then search for the string: user_id     . That should show you where the user_id property is exactly in the object/variable

Comment: I do know how to find it in the text, what i dont know is how to interpret the result and figure out the full variable to get it.

Comment: If you would post the output I can tell you right away; but I am assuming there may be sensitive data in there.

Comment: Yes, thats right. Thats another reason why i cant post it. But i did post part of it in my question. I know it might be useless but its something.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is an alias of whatever class it is called from. so `user_id` would come from `$this->user_id`, which is just an alias of `$user_id`. it is commonly a null variable at the top of the class, ie it has to be created by the class.

Comment: I tried that one but wont work. It would be useful a function that outputs all the possible variables.